# Conveying the verb 'drive'

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, verbes

Pour

> If you really want to dig into the programming philosophy that **drives**
> much of the coding practice of Python power users, you should read
> this book.

Google Translate donne

> Si vous voulez vraiment vous plonger dans la philosophie de
> programmation qui **sous-tend** une grande partie de la pratique de codage
> des utilisateurs expérimentés de Python, vous devriez lire ce livre.

mais je pense qu'un locuteur natif n'utilisera pas sous-tendre dans cette phrase. Suis-je correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voici quelques verbes qui peuvent convenir ici :

> [...] la philosophie qui **détermine** une grande partie [...]
> [...] la philosophie qui **oriente** une grande partie [...]
> [...] la philosophie qui **inspire** une grande partie [...]

Answer (score 3):

« Sous-tend » n'est pas une mauvaise traduction ; je dirais qu'elle est même plutôt bonne. On peut lui reprocher de négliger un aspect de l'idée qui existe dans le verbe anglais ; « to drive » a le sens de « [to give impetus](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the/french-word-for-c2c9fe41494c15934003dab6fb5aec91e3151057.html) », qui peut prendre diverses formes (donner une impulsion, donner de l'impulsion, donne son impulsion, …), et donc l'expression « donner son impulsion » est encore une possibilité que l'on pourra choisir.

- Si vous voulez vraiment vous plonger dans la philosophie de programmation qui *donne son impulsion* à une grande partie de la pratique de codage des utilisateurs expérimentés de Python, vous devriez lire ce livre.